# Drag and drop NOT working with Gmail in Firefox, on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, firefox, gmail, drag-and-drop

Dragging and dropping files in Gmail is not working in Ubuntu 18.04 and Mozilla Firefox.

I trap the file, drag it to the mail box (drop your file here) and nothing happens (The image of the file returns to its original place. Sometimes the "drop your file here" Gmail box remains frozen) The file never is attached.

Comment: Same problem here, Firefox 63.0.3, Manjaro KDE

Comment: @Carlos How are you dragging the file, i.e. Clicking and dragging with one finger or holding and dragging with two fingers (if using touchpad of laptop) or with mouse?

Comment: Hi! The problem is with the desktop version of Firefox using either the touchpad or the mouse. May be this video can help to describe the issue: https://youtu.be/2tmBIvW0Gp0
Thanks!

Comment: That video is exactly what happens to me!

Answer (score 7):

It happens to me too, only in Gmail, weird that it doesn't happen in Google Drive.

A workaround I just found is to make a fast return to the window from I'm getting the file while dragging to a Gmail's message, then drop the file in the Gmail's message area and it will be attached as expected. [Look at this video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IH_1RMxoUV-YTvPQJT3tFj3JfRTfgkRq).

Comment: It is not working for me anymore. Is it for you?

Comment: It works better with one file, multiple files require a lot of "gaming" with the drag and drop movements... Now, when I need to attach multiple files, I'm working around this using the [Attach to Thunderbird service menu for Dolphin](https://store.kde.org/search/projectSearchText/thunderbird).

Comment: This workaround works for me, but only if I "jump" directly from my folder to the Gmail window. If the file "flies over" another window, the problem will be the same.

Comment: Not working for me any more :(

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, however I think it is still an issue with Firefox

Comment: I don't think it's an issue with Firefox because the only site where it occurs is in GMail, not even in Google Drive, so, it have to be an issue with GMail which may be is not compliant with drag and drop on web standars.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what works for me: while holding the mouse button down, drag the cursor into the compose pane, then outside the Firefox window, and then reenter slowly from the bottom part of the compose pane. Once the cursor turns into a hand with a "+" sign, you can drop the file(s). This way it works 99% of the time.

It usually doesn't work if you reenter from the sides, or from above, or from the bottom part of the window but outside the compose pane.

You can also try directly entering the Firefox window from the bottom of the compose pane without doing the exit/enter voodoo mentioned above, but it works maybe 50% of the time.

Super weird, I know...

Comment: That works for me too (your first paragraph). Thanks gpothier!

Comment: This works really well. Changed my life back to normal after months of disruption.

Comment: This trick requires non-maximized Gmail windows;  and i couldn't make it work under latest debian.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to me is to click on the "Attach files" button, and drop the file(s) in the file selection window that opens. This always works.

Comment: same issue on windows, although in my case it was that you cannot drag and drop any files from Windows Explorer into an application that is opened as Administrator (I was running Firefox in that mode)

Comment: @kkarakk Since in Linux the problem is only in GMail, I wouldn't say it's the same problem.

Comment: it happens for me in both gmail and drive in linux and windows and is fixed when i disable admin mode/change permissions on firefox using chmod, i suspect it's a permissions issue by programs launching other programs with elevated permissions(for eg it was vscode doing it in my case)

Comment: @kkarakk I open Firefox myself, and don't use Google Drive.

Comment: Please do not ask (rhetoric and/or opinionated) questions/commentaries in *answers*, if needed use a comment. An answer should only contain a focussed and objective *answer*. How's that supposed to "just lead to the solution"? If you have any documentation supporting this "theory", then add it with the proper citation in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Try holding the file and from your keyboard use alt+tab.
Works for me for Gmail, G-Drive, Whatsapp.